# How to create Sticky Header in a ScrollingActivity

Tags: java, android

I used ScrollActivity that comes in android studio to create a cool animation while scrolling. The ScrollActivity came with two xml files which are content_scrolling.xml and activity_scrolling.xml. I would like to create sticky headers inside the content_scrolling.xml. I created sticky headers before but the problem I am having is that the header does not "stick" right under the image where I'd like it to instead it sticks on top of the screen which is blocked by the image. I have provided an image of what I am trying to accomplish and I hope it helps understand what I am trying to do. Thank you!

[image]

activity_scrolling.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.myapplication.foodapp.ScrollingActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="545dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@mipmap/food1"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Chipotle Chicken Fajitas"
            android:textSize="27sp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/first_food_title"/>

        <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="16 ingredients | 284 Calories | 1 hour"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/spec_text"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            />



        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/arrow"
            android:id="@id/back_Arrow"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_scrolling.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.myapplication.foodapp.ScrollingActivity"
android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2000dp"
    android:background="#fff">


    <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
        android:id="@+id/spec_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="16 ingredients | 284 Calories | 1 hour"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        app:sizeToFit="true"/>



    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="#2C7873"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView3"
        android:id="@+id/ingredient_view"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:src="@drawable/servings"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ingredients"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView3"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bullet_one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5px" 
        android:text="@string/_1_lb_boneless_skinless_chicken_breasts_cut_into_thin_strips"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bullet_two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bullet_one"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/_1_tsp_ground_cumin"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bullet_three"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bullet_two"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/_1_tsp_chili_powder"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bullet_four"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bullet_three"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/kosher_salt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bullet_five"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bullet_four"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/freshly_ground_black_pepper"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bullet_six"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bullet_five"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/_1_tbsp_canola_oil"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bullet_seven"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bullet_six"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/_1_red_bell_pepper_sliced"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bullet_eight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bullet_seven"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/_1_small_onion_sliced"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bullet_nine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bullet_eight"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/_1_c_sliced_mushrooms"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bullet_ten"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bullet_nine"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/_3_garlic_cloves_chopped"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bullet_elven"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bullet_ten"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/_1_tbsp_chopped_chipotles_in_adobo"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bullet_twelve"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bullet_ten"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/_1_1_2_tbsp_fresh_lime_juice"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bullet_thirteen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bullet_twelve"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/_8_warm_flour_tortillas"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bullet_fithteen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bullet_thirteen"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/cilantro_for_serving"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bullet_sixteen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bullet_fithteen"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/lime_wedges_for_serving"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bullet_fourteen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bullet_sixteen"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/grated_cheddar_cheese_for_serving"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView23"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="View Directions"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bullet_fourteen"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="#2C7873"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView23"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView3"
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:tag="sticky"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Nutrition Facts"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView23"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView23" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="View More"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:paddingEnd="15dp"
        android:paddingStart="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/protein" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView18"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView18"
            android:src="@drawable/sodium" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView19"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView19"
            android:src="@drawable/fats" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView21"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView20"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView20"
            android:src="@drawable/sugars" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#2C7873"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:tag="sticky"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Reviews"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView15" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:scaleX=".5"
        android:scaleY=".5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_review"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f1fcf0"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: which is your sticky head ?

Comment: I want textview "Ingredients, Nutrition Facts, and Reviews" to all be sticky headers

Comment: they are located inside the content_scrolling.xml

Comment: you have to include it in appbarlayout